# Couldn't add Apple Id into Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have read similar questions but they don't fit my situation.

So I have a developer Apple Id account (and I agreed with Apple terms&conditions) and I can use it on the Mac both in XCode and Visual Studio.

But when I'm trying to add the same account into Visual Studio on my desktop:

[image]

I get the next error:

[image]

What can be the issue?

P.S. I tried this in VS 16.5.0 and 16.5.1.

**Update from 10.12.20**
I tried several VS versions till 16.9.0 Preview 2.0, and the problem still exists. The last working VS version was 16.4.6, but I cannot use it due to Xcode and Xamarin updates.

In IDE log I see an exception:

> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl|Information|0|Client --- -
> An application message for topic
> ---/error/xvs/idb/add-developer-account was received
> Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient|Error|0|An error occurred on
> the receiver while executing a post for topic
> xvs/idb/add-developer-account and client ---
> Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MessagingRemoteException: An error
> occurred on client IDBLocal1--- while executing a reply for topic
> xvs/idb/add-developer-account --->
> Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.AppleProvisioningException: An error
> occurred while sending the request.    at
> Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.AppleProvisioningManager.d__13.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\A\1\5\s\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local\AppleProvisioningManager.cs:line
> 108
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.AppleProvisioningManager.d__10.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\A\1\5\s\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local\AppleProvisioningManager.cs:line
> 53
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local.AddDeveloperAccountHandler.d__5.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\A\1\5\s\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local\Handlers\AddDeveloperAccountHandler.cs:line
> 26
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.Messaging.Client.RequestHandler`2.<HandleAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\400\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\Handlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessageHandlerManager.<>c__DisplayClass16_1`2.<b__2>d.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\A\1\400\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessageHandlerManager.cs:line
> 0
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.d__32`2.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\400\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 0 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.ApplicationMessageExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.b__1(MqttApplicationMessage
> m) in
> C:\A\1\400\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\Extensions\ApplicationMessageExtensions.cs:line
> 194    at
> System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Select`2.Selector._.OnNext(TSource value) in d:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Linq\Observable\Select.cs:line 39 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__21`2.MoveNext()
> in C:\A\1\400\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line
> 190 System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client
> --- - Dispatching Publish message to flow PublishReceiverFlow
> and topic ---/response/xma/ping/Broker1---

and in Xamarin.IOS log:

> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl: Information: 0: Client
> IDBLocal---- - An application message for topic
> xvs/idb/add-developer-account was received: 2020-12-10 11:08:06Z
> Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.AppleProvisioningManager: Error: 0:
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
> the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted:
> Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.    at
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult
> ar)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.DeveloperPortalWebClient.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<b__2>d.MoveNext()
> in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/AppleDeveloperPortal/DeveloperPortalWebClient.cs:line
> 127
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.DeveloperPortalWebClient.d__25.MoveNext()
> in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/AppleDeveloperPortal/DeveloperPortalWebClient.cs:line
> 125
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.AppleIDAuthenticationProvider.d__42.MoveNext()
> in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/AppleDeveloperPortal/AppleIDAuthenticationProvider.cs:line
> 411
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.AppleIDAuthenticationProvider.d__30.MoveNext()
> in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/AppleDeveloperPortal/AppleIDAuthenticationProvider.cs:line
> 115
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.AppleIDAuthenticationProvider.d__29.MoveNext()
> in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/AppleDeveloperPortal/AppleIDAuthenticationProvider.cs:line
> 109
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.AuthorizedDeveloperPortalClient.d__4.MoveNext()
> in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/AppleDeveloperPortal/AuthorizedDeveloperPortalClient.cs:line
> 47
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.AppleDeveloperPortal.d__46.MoveNext()
> in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/AppleDeveloperPortal/AppleDeveloperPortal.cs:line
> 939
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.SyncDeveloperInfo.d__5.MoveNext() in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/ProvisioningTasks/SyncDeveloperInfo.cs:line
> 50
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.SyncDeveloperAccountData`1.<Run>d__17.MoveNext() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/ProvisioningTasks/SyncDeveloperAccountData.cs:line 62 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.AppleProvisioningManager.<GetUpdatedAccountByUsernameAsync>d__13.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\5\s\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local\AppleProvisioningManager.cs:line 94: 2020-12-10 11:08:09Z Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient: Error: 0: An error occurred on client IDBLocal169000196 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/add-developer-account Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.AppleProvisioningException: An error occurred while sending the request.    at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.AppleProvisioningManager.<GetUpdatedAccountByUsernameAsync>d__13.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\5\s\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local\AppleProvisioningManager.cs:line 108 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.AppleProvisioningManager.<AddDeveloperAccountAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\5\s\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local\AppleProvisioningManager.cs:line 53 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local.AddDeveloperAccountHandler.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\5\s\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local\Handlers\AddDeveloperAccountHandler.cs:line 26 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.RequestHandler`2.d__5.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\A\1\400\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\Handlers\RequestHandler.cs:line
> 0
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessageHandlerManager.<>c__DisplayClass16_1`2.<<RegisterHandlerAsync>b__2>d.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\400\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessageHandlerManager.cs:line 0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<ReplyAsync>d__32`2.MoveNext()
> in C:\A\1\400\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line
> 0: 2020-12-10 11:08:09Z

Comment: Are you getting to the 2 factor authentication step?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. As I seen before, no 2 factor authentication required during adding an apple account.

Comment: Maybe it's a setting on my side. I've tried adding the account and after entering the username and password I'm asked for 2 factor authentication.
Have you tried on another machine?

Comment: As I remember, no 2nd step was required during adding (it should be a local setting, I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. The problem was in SSL/TLS settings. I followed [this](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/8176#issuecomment-683923724) recommendation and now it works.